# Transparent bar along my render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

This is a new one for me.... For some reason, my renders are creating this transparent bar on the far right. I have no compositing happening.

[image]

UPDATE: I've never seen this before but I think this was the issue as it's fixed but I'm very confused why it's even there in the first place as I've never seen it on any of my other projects before. These weird corner cropping things were moved. I don't know what this is or how it became visible (I must of accidentally turned it on and moved it or something) Any idea what this is?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had render region selected.